# TextView change when onClick in RecyclerView

Tags: android, position, android-recyclerview, adapter

I try to setText in RecyclerView, but I don't know how to setText position by onClick.

This is My Adapter

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final PhotoViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    holder.plus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (mContext instanceof PhotoPicker) {
                ((PhotoPicker) mContext).tambahFoto(position);

            }
        }
    });
}
```

This is My Activity

```
public void tambahFoto(int position) {
    if(jumlahFoto < 15) {
        jumlahFoto = jumlahFoto + 1;
        selectedPhotos.set(position, String.valueOf(jumlahFoto));
        photo_cropAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        TextView tampilan = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.totalFoto);

        Integer count = Integer.parseInt(tampilan.getText().toString());

        count++;
        tampilan.setText("" + count);
        jum.setText(jumlahFoto+"/ 15 Photo");
        }

    }
```

Thanks :)

Comment: holder.tampilan.setText(YOUR_TEXT);